# How to display parameter values at every iteration while using Genetic algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, parameters, genetic-algorithm

I am using GA to solve for 6 parameters using the global optimization toolbox.

Is there a way to display the parameter values at every iteration of GA. I can use display or iter but it doesn't necessarily display the parameter values.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [plot functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html#f14474).
You can either use one of the predefined plot functions:

```
options = gaoptimset('PlotFcns',@gaplotbestf);
x= ga(@f,6,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options)
```

or you can write your own. For example:

```
function gademo
    options= gaoptimset('PlotFcns',@myplot,'PopulationSize',10);
    x= ga(@f,6,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options)

    function y= f(x) % the fitness function
        y= norm(x);
    end
        % simple plot function
    function state= myplot(options,state,flag)
        fprintf('generation number: %d\n',state.Generation);
        fprintf('population:\n');
        disp(state.Population);
    end
end
```

Comment: This works and I am able to display other values using this routine. Thank you very much for helping me with this!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the function [fprintf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)?

For example, if you wanted to print the first element of vector x, which is a float, to the screen:

```
fprintf(1,'%f\n', x(1))
```

You can see how to format numbers and strings in the documentation of fprintf if you scroll down a bit under formatSpec.

Comment: Yes, I did but maybe I was not using it properly. Based on AVK's comment, I was able to display the results using fprintf and disp options. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it!